# Same Instance of class being duplicated

Tags: javascript, class, javascript-objects

I am trying to create a way to print out a tile based grid of squares for a game. It is a 2D rpg style game so I would like to have different properties for different tiles (collision, different art, etc). Currently I have a base class for a tiles and an array called tileObjectDirectory for tiles that I have given properties and would essentially like to copy and paste on the grid. My problem is that I am trying to assign x and y values to where they should be printed but it seems that each type of tile I push in are getting assigned the same value. For example all the path tiles are getting the same X value. Is this a problem with how I am initializing each tile?

```
//blank tile class
class tile {

constructor(name, ID, x, y) {
this.name = name;
this.ID = ID;   
this.x = x;
this.y = y;
}

}

//defining tiles
let Path = new tile("path", "p", 0, 0);
let Test = new tile("test", "t", 0, 0);


//this array store all the current types of tiles in the game
//let tileObjectDirectory = [Path, Test];
let tileObjectDirectory = [new tile("path", "p", 0, 0), new tile("test", "t", 0, 0)];

function tileSelector(tileID) {
let tileObject;

switch (tileID) {
    case "p":
        tileObject = tileObjectDirectory[0];
        break;
    case "t":
        tileObject = tileObjectDirectory[1];
        break;
    }

return tileObject;
}

//takes in an array of tile id's chars and outputs an array of the corresponding tile objects
function initializeTileObjects(tileIDArray) {
let tileObjects = [];
let tileX = 0;
let tileY = 0;

//go through array of ids and put the correct objects in the new array
for (let i = 0; i < tileIDArray.length; i++) {
//tileObjects[i] = tileSelector(tileIDArray[i]);
tileObjects.push(tileSelector(tileIDArray[i]));

console.log(`initializing i = ${i}:`, tileObjects[i]);
}
//console.log("before:", tileObjects);

//assigning the correct coordinates to the tiles
for (let i = 0; i < tileObjects.length; i++) {
tileObjects[i].x = tileX;
//tileObject[i].y = tileY;
tileX += 1;
console.log(`tileX = ${tileX}, i = ${i}`);
}

console.log(tileObjects);

return tileObjects;
}

//main function for creating a map
function createMap(tileIDArray) {

tileObjectArray = initializeTileObjects(tileIDArray);

console.log(tileObjectArray);
}
```

And I am calling createMap(); like this,

```
createMap(["p", "t", "p", "p", "p", "p", "p", "p", 
       "p", "p", "p", "p", "t", "t", "t", "t"]);
```

Comment: `tileObjectDirectory` only contains two objects, i.e. you only have two tiles, not 16. You can’t have more than two distinct positions if you only have two objects.

Comment: [Duplicate](//google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+setting+property+in+one+object+sets+the+same+property+in+all+other+objects) of [Javascript object when setting property all properties with same name are set](/q/50999351/4642212).

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. Also, that post is just what I was looking for. Thank you!